# What is the significance of Dua Simat?

Tags: hadith, sunni, dua, reference-request

I am reading the wikipedia page on Dua Simat دعاء السمات, but it does not clearly reference any Islamic texts.

Are there any (sunni) hadiths relating to this Dua?

Edit:
From wiki,

*The initial (English translated) part of Du'a Simat is:*

*Allah! I beseech Thee through Thy Name, the most great, the most majestic, the most magnificent and the most noble. If Thou art requested therewith to open the closed doors of the sky these will open with Thy mercy. If Thou art requested thereby to remove the narrowness of the doors of the heaven, they will be opened wide. If Thou art requested thereby to make easy the dif..*

اللّـهُمَّ اِنّى اَسْأَلُكَ بِاسْمِكَ الْعَظيمِ الْاَعْظَمِ الْاَعَزِّ الْاَجَلِّ الْاَكْرَمِ الَّذى اِذا دُعيتَ بِهِ عَلى مَغالِقِ اَبْوابِ السَّمآءِ لِلْفَتْحِ بِالرَّحْمَةِ انْفَتَحَتْ، وَاِذا دُعيتَ بِهِ عَلى مَضآئِقِ اَبْوابِ الْاَرْضِ لِلْفَرَجِ انْفَرَجَتْ، وَاِذا دُعيتَ بِهِ عَلَى العُسْرِ لِلْيُسْرِ تَيَسَّرَتْ، وَاِذا دُعيتَ بِهِ عَلَى الْاَمْواتِ لِلنُّشُورِ انْتَشَرَتْ، وَاِذا دُعيتَ بِهِ عَلى كَشْفِ الْبَأسآءِ وَالضَّرّاءِ انْكَشَفَتْ، … [[Source]](http://qadatona.org/%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AF%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA/19)

Comment: This du'a can be found in shi'a sources and they attribute it to ahl-al-Bayt pretending it includes Allah's most powerful (or best) name الاسم الأعظم. The length of the du'a and its wording actually makes these claims doubtful. Shi'a claim it is a powerful du'a and recommend performing it at the end of 'Asr time on Friday's. Alone Arabic Wikipedia provides more than 30 commentaries explaining this du'a.